# Sorting on the property of a nested collection in OData

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api2, odata

We have the object model similar to the one below,

```
context.People
  .include('Children')
  .include('Children.FavoriteColor')
  .order('Name')
  .order('Children.Name')
  .order('Children.FavoriteColor.Brightness')
```

There is an OData Query that needs to filter by Brightness.

We tried with the following

`$expand=Children&$orderby=Children/FavoriteColor/Brightness` 
but it gives error because the FavoriteColor is a collection. However, there is also the Primary Keys added by default in the generated SQL from EF before any of the orderby columns.

Kindly suggest how the filtering can be done based on the Brightness [Child collection property using OData]

This issue is similar to this [query](https://github.com/jaystack/jaydata/issues/62)